# Ubuntu 14.04 cannot start after upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I have just upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04, but now I can not start up the system.

I have tried to go to advanced options and newest recovery mode - root - and command `fsck -A` - as recommended - then fix network - and dpkg options.

After this I ended up in the console where Ubuntu ask me to logg in. I press my name (kenneth) and then password.

After this it says:

```
welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1LTS
*Documentation: https: //help.ubuntu.com/
Kenneth@ubuntu:$:
```

What command must i give to start up from there?

Comment: Well try the following, `sudo lightdm`  and if that doesn't work go back to tty (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and do `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: i tried that but nothing happens when i press sudo lightdm and when i press sudo apt-get install -f, it says done and that i have nothing to upgrade, install or remove and 6 not to upgrade.

Comment: Okay, `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: okay have done that too. It says something about 2 packages that have been kept back. I should probably also says that when i was at recovery and pressed "fsck -A" it told me something blocked. It was a long number that blocked?

Answer (score 1):

First, addressing something in the comments above: To get the ones that were held back type `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

If `sudo lightdm` doesn't work after you've done the above (and rebooted!) try typing

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

EDIT: As per the below comments, if the above doesn't work, try:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

If the second line gives an error saying the it's not installed do

```
sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. First i do dist-upgrade, then sudo lightdm - nothing happens, it does not react on ctrl+alt+f1 command. I do the last command you mentioned and following Things happens: "Some packages could not be installed. This may mean you have requested an imposible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of incomming. The following packages have unmet dependencies (then comes a long list) Last thing: E: Unable to correct problems, you have broken packages.

Comment: Maybe i also should tell, that i for some time now have had problems connecting 12.04 Linux with my printer and this have coursed some "funny" things in console when i update from there. I dont know if this have anything to do with this.

Comment: For that last bit, try doing the following: `sudo apt-get install aptitude` and then `aptitude reinstall ubuntu-desktop` it should give you a few options (hopefully!) but and allow you to fix the issue

Comment: It says after the first one: Unable to locate package apitude. And after the second command: No command "apitude" found, did you mean command: "apitude" from package "apitude" main. apitude: command not found.

Comment: "aptitude" you're missing the first 't'.

Comment: oh sorry about that. First command tells me: "aptitude is already the newest version". Second command: ubuntu-desktop is not currently installed, so it will not be reinstalled.

Comment: How to install ubuntu-desktop - Maybe this is it?

Comment: Try `aptitude install ubuntu-desktop` and see what it tells you. Some background here: Aptitude is a front-end to apt-get, and it is usually a little bit better at resolving dependencies/broken packages

Comment: Yes - it Works. Thanks so much. I never would have found out this my self. Really very friendly of you musher. I appreciate it a lot. After i got it - it ask me if i want to report a problem - should i say yes to this og cancel?

Comment: It certainly can't hurt to report the problem, hopefully it will save someone else some work when you're all through with it.

Comment: okay problem have been reported. It told me something about an internal Ubuntu problem. I am in now and writing from Firefox. Looks strange however that console is just a black box. I can open it but i cant write anything in the console - like i said - just a black box?

Comment: I would definitely do another `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to make sure everything is up-to-date. If you can't access a terminal through the normal means (selecting it through the unity launcher) you can type `ctrl alt f1` to get into a terminal. Press `ctrl alt f7` to return to the graphical interface.

Comment: okay i have tried that and i can enter terminal this way, but after i return the problem still there. There is definitely something wrong with console, because it also act strange when i try inlarge it - full screen. I need to go to work now, but if still there tomorrow i write another question about it. There is no problem starting restarting computer now and it is 14.04LTS version.

Comment: Okay I have also found a solution on this last problem. Everything works perfectly now. Once again thanks for helping me out. Problem solved.

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark the question as answered for other people who stumble across the issue!